# Add a class to prepended text only

Tags: jquery, html, dom, addclass

How can I add a class to a prepended text, without adding it to the entire label. So far I have this:

```
$('form label').prepend('*');
$(this).addClass('star');
```

But I know 'this' refers to the label. I would like to add a class to every asterisk.

Comment: If `$(this)` refers to the label why not just `$(this).prepend('*')`? Is this code occurring in an `.each()` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to have a tag in order to add an attribute such as class:

```
$('form label').prepend('<span class="star">*</span>');
```

**or**

```
$('<span class="star">*</span>').prependTo('form label');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't add a class to the `*` because it's just a text node. You have to wrap it with an element node like a `span`. And, if you're going to do that much, you can just specify the class at the same time:

```
$('form label').prepend('<span class="star">*</span>');
```

Comment: Downvoter: Please take a moment to read what a downvote is for so you can know how to properly use this site http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down